# Typescript function overload, generic optional parameter

Tags: typescript, overloading

I'm having trouble understanding how to properly type a function passed as a parameter to another function where the passed function can have 2 different signatures, one with a param the other without param.

I have a reduced case that looks like this:

```js
type ApiMethod<T, U> = {
  (payload?: T): Promise<U>;
};

function callFactory<T, U>(apiMethod: ApiMethod<T, U>) {
  return async (payload?: T): Promise<U> => {
    if (payload) {
      return await apiMethod(payload);
    } else {
      return await apiMethod();
    }
  };
}

const apiMethodExample1: (payload: string) => Promise<string> = (payload) => {
  return Promise.resolve('some payload: ' + payload);
};

const apiMethodExample2: () => Promise<string> = () => {
  return Promise.resolve('no payload');
};

const call1 = callFactory(apiMethodExample1); // here TS complains
const call2 = callFactory(apiMethodExample2);

const value1 = call1('examplePayload').then((value: string) => console.log(value));
const value2 = call2().then((value) => console.log(value));
```

[here the code in the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=60#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmCWBZCwAWB7AJgHgCoBooBVAPigF4oBvAKCigAowBDEAG3WcwC4pcBKXgAUATugC28AM4RspANx1GLdp0wB%20XgOFjJMuSUUBfRTQBmAVwB2AY2Dx0VqDeZs2AMWZ30IkHkKkDMwIyGhYvHBIKBg4BMQk-NRKIigWIk7MUiC2yqwcXJp8glCiEtKypBRktPT08Ga5qlyJNbX0KcBpGQDuzPDAUMFRYZhMeWr8im1GUBBsMklt7anpg739gyHRWAyTSvRGSiY0hzQ2jlIDQ6ExAKIAHsziYGwQAIy8Y008UJci8FYAOaJchkUp6WR-AGAsiUL75TAg6rJFZOcHlAB0KSk6DYADcIAwAOQ48TQFQI3hEqAAaigFImxlM5ysl02wzuj2erwATJ8kSVdOVsFCgbDGALWh0uoKyjIsRAcfjCUSrOh6eMuES9sczhcBi43G8KM5XB4vMAfCAglsRg8ni93nsWWzDWweSa3Z5vL4bRysPbuRAeXs9ayBnjXBZ3p6zW9iRAuY6hJrMNqMWgIFYGAxI2xo7xRcCqs4LriIBiOIDc1GIPxnfqoHnox7KG6ebsM6gsznm3WSy7y5X0NW%20-X5EA)

My problem is that TS complains that in

`const call1 = callFactory(apiMethodExample1);`

```
Argument of type '(payload: string) => Promise<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ApiMethod<string, string>'.
  Types of parameters 'payload' and 'payload' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I feel like I am not overloading the *apiMethod* param properly
but all my other attempts have failed as well

I have looked at this answer: [Typescript function overloads with generic optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208569/typescript-function-overloads-with-generic-optional-parameters)

but could not apply it to my case

thanks for any help

Comment: The problem here is that the `ApiMethod` definition includes functions with an optional payload. Since your `apiMethodExample1` function requires it's payload argument, it is not assignable to `ApiMethod` where that argument is optional.

Comment: Thanks @CRice - I'm starting to understand. I'm just looking for a way to be able to pass both methods to the factory. Does that seem feasible? or, as I've started to think, the only way to cast methods to the proper type when passing them to the factory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this type:

```
type ApiMethod<T, U> = {
  (payload: T): Promise<U>;
  (payload?: T): Promise<U>;
};
```

If you give me a value `f` of type `ApiMethod<string, string>`, I should be able to call `f("someString")` and I should *also* be able to call `f()`.  Overloaded functions have multiple call signatures and need to be callable for *each* of the call signatures.

If I call `f()` and everything explodes, then you haven't given me a valid `ApiMethod<string, string>`.  And that's what the compiler is complaining about for `apiMethodExample1`.

---

Let me modify the implementation of `apiMethodExample1` slightly:

```
const apiMethodExample1: (payload: string) => Promise<string> = (payload) => {
  return Promise.resolve('some payload: ' + payload.toUpperCase());
};
```

All I've done here is uppercase the `payload`, which is a `string`, so it should have a `toUpperCase()` method.  This is no different from your version of `apiMethodExample1` from the type system's point of view, since the implementation details are not visible from outside of the function.

If the compiler didn't complain about this:

```
const call1 = callFactory(apiMethodExample1);
```

then because the type of `call1` is inferred as

```
// const call1: (payload?: string | undefined) => Promise<string>
```

and so you are allowed to do this:

```
call1().then(s => console.log(s));
```

which explodes at runtime with

```
// TypeError: payload is undefined
```

The problem is that `apiMethodExample1` can only be safely used as a `(payload: string): Promise<string>` and not as the full set of call signatures required by `ApiMethod<string, string>`.

---

Note that `apiMethodExample2` is fine because the single signature `() => Promise<string>` is assignable to *both* call signatures.  It might be surprising that `() => Promise<string>` is assignable to `(payload: string) => Promise<string>`, but that's because you can safely use the former as the latter, as the former will ignore any parameter passed to it.  See the TypeScript FAQ entry called [Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) for more information.

---

Aside: note that if your code weren't just a reduced example, I'd strongly suggest removing the first overload signature because any function that satisfies the second one will also satisfy the first one.  So this particular example doesn't really have to do with overloads per se; you get the same behavior if you just write

```
type ApiMethod<T, U> = {
  (payload?: T): Promise<U>;
};
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-n4Qrt4Ph+hR-f9+OiyNv7Kh6lu2aA3nee4QK+NzviO4EPpBzZAA)

---

### UPDATE:

It looks like you want to type `callFactory()` to accept both types, and not that you really care about `ApiMethod<T, U>` at all.  If so, I'd write it this way:

```
function callFactory<T extends [] | [any], U>(apiMethod: (...payload: T) => Promise<U>) {
  return async (...payload: T): Promise<U> => {
    return await apiMethod(...payload);
  };
}
```

No conditional code inside the implementation; it just spreads the arguments into the call.  And `callFactory` is typed so that the function it returns takes the same arguments as the passed-in `apiMethod`.  It's not clear why you even need `callFactory` since all it does is return something of the same type as its argument (`callFactory(apiMethodExample1)` and `apiMethodExample1` are basically the same thing), but that's your reduced example code, I guess.

Anyway, everything after that will just work:

```
const call1 = callFactory(apiMethodExample1); // okay
const call2 = callFactory(apiMethodExample2); // okay

const value1 = call1('examplePayload').then((value: string) => console.log(value));
const value2 = call2().then((value) => console.log(value));

call1() // error
call2("hey"); // error
```

Hope that helps. Good luck again.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: This is a very clear, well thought out explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I'm still struggling to really understand so I have to spend a little time with it.

For now I'll edit the question to remove the unnecessary overload

Comment: so, I have found that the only way to make this work would be to assert that _apiMethodExample1_ has to be used _as ApiMethod<string, string>_. Is that right? Or is there a way I can modify the _callFactory_ to accept both methods without having to cast ?

Comment: I updated my answer... assuming you want to "make things work" by ignoring the `ApiMethod` definition you gave and just type `callFactory()` with enough flexibility to support the way you want to call it

Comment: Thanks again, this looks like what I'm after indeed. Being able to pass a method that accepts 0 or more arguments as my apiMethods can have. The factory is useless here I know but it is used to add functionality (logging ... ) and the code for that has been omitted (maybe there is a better way ...) - as for the way you wrote it this time I can't say I understand it right now, I'm struggling with the extends and spread part, any resource you'd recommend?

Comment: The `extends` is a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).  We are constraining the list of arguments to `[] | [any]`, meaning a tuple of length 0 or a tuple of length 1.

Comment: The spread/rest part is using [tuple types as arg lists](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), where [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is from JS.

Answer (score 1):

I've added "overloads" to methods in classes before with this pattern.

```
genUpdateItem<T>(data: [T, IStringAnyMap]): void;

genUpdateItem<T, S>(data: [T, IStringAnyMap], options?: S): void;

genUpdateItem<T, S>(data: [T, IStringAnyMap], options?: S): void {
  // do the work in this method
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I could find find a way to do just that for the method I'm passing to the factory, I might (...) be confused but I don't see how I can do it.